# onclick is not working with MaterialRippleLayout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

i am using `MaterialRippleLayout` to a an image for Ripple effect in my app. And in my activity i implemented the code on click image its will start new Activity without `MaterialRippleLayout` my code is working fine. but with `MaterialRippleLayout` click is not working. bellow is my code.

```
<com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ripple"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true"
                    app:mrl_rippleColor="#000"
                    app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.2"
                    app:mrl_rippleDimension="10dp"
                    app:mrl_rippleHover="true"
                    app:mrl_rippleRoundedCorners="10dp"
                    app:mrl_rippleInAdapter="false"
                    app:mrl_rippleDuration="350"
                    app:mrl_rippleFadeDuration="75"
                    app:mrl_rippleDelayClick="false"
                    app:mrl_rippleBackground="#FFF"
                    app:mrl_ripplePersistent="true">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="160dp"
                        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
```

and below is my dependence

```
compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
```

my java code in adapter is

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        public TextView title, count;
        public ImageView thumbnail;

        ArrayList<Catagory> CatagoryList = new ArrayList<Catagory>();
        Context mContext;

        public MyViewHolder(View view , Context mContext, ArrayList<Catagory> CatagoryList ) {
            super(view);
            this.CatagoryList = CatagoryList;
            this.mContext = mContext;
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
            thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            Catagory CatagoryList = this.CatagoryList.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this.mContext, CatagoryVendListActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("CatId", CatagoryList.getVendId());
            intent.putExtra("CatName", CatagoryList.getName());
            this.mContext.startActivity(intent);


        }
    }
```

Please comment if you have any doubts.

Comment: can you post you java code for `onClick`?

Comment: i had added java code onClick

Comment: Where is initialization of this id: `ripple` view?

Comment: how to initialise ripple view i tried MaterialRippleLayout mRipple; mRipple.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(ac, " clicked in mripple", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs of the library, you can initialize ripple view as following:

```
MaterialRippleLayout.on(view)
       .rippleColor(Color.BLACK)
       .create();
```

Where `view` is your view, to which you want to set this effect.

Now to set onClickListener, use the following code:

```
findViewById(R.id.ripple).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View v) {
        //handle click here. 
    }
});
```

Comment: this is not the answer i am looking, but you give me idea. i added mRipple = (MaterialRippleLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ripple);
            MaterialRippleLayout.on(mRipple).create();
            mRipple.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: i accepted  you answer, please check i added my answer

Answer (score 0):

Those who are looking for the same solution. below is my answer

```
private MaterialRippleLayout mRipple;

 public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        public TextView title, count;
        public ImageView thumbnail;

        ArrayList<Catagory> CatagoryList = new ArrayList<Catagory>();
        Context mContext;

        public MyViewHolder(View view , Context mContext, ArrayList<Catagory> CatagoryList ) {
            super(view);
            this.CatagoryList = CatagoryList;
            this.mContext = mContext;
            //view.setOnClickListener(this);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
            thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            mRipple = (MaterialRippleLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ripple);
            MaterialRippleLayout.on(mRipple).create();
            mRipple.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            Catagory CatagoryList = this.CatagoryList.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this.mContext, CatagoryVendListActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("CatId", CatagoryList.getVendId());
            intent.putExtra("CatName", CatagoryList.getName());
            this.mContext.startActivity(intent);


        }
    }
```